# VS Code 'cannot open source file "stdio.h" C/C++'

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-code, intellisense

In the below image attached, I am getting error as cannot open source file "header file name" for both C as well as C++ headers.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/khIyN.png]

How to fix this error for all the files.

Comment: Can you show some code?

Comment: C or C++? Pick one! As a new user here, also take the [tour] and read [ask], because it isn't even clear what exactly you were doing.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt for both C as well as C++, for C++ it is not detecting <iostream> header.

Comment: Do not post just an image....

Comment: Please share some code and also refer to @UlrichEckhardt comment.
What I understood from your question, https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/cpp
this link may help you. Please look into it.

Answer (score 1):

This means that the vs code intellisense is looking at the header files wrong directory. You should see a bulb icon when you hover over the `#include` click it and you should see options regarding the location where it is looking for the headers.

Answer (score 1):

I have same problem! There are a lot of solutions on the internet. But I could not use any of them...
I downloaded a visual studio solution in the internet but I could not built it! I got the error of "Can not open source file ..." for all C/C++ library.
The solution was really simple.

1. Right click on the project under the solution.
2. Select properties (Alt+Enter)
3. Under the "Configuration Properties" select "VC++ Directories"
4. In the right panel select "include Directories"
5. At the end of its value add "$(includePath);"
6. Apply change and enjoy of bug fix :)

Comment: This solution worked for me in Visual studio 2019 (16.4.4)